# GWT: When to use Button and when to use ButtonCell

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, widget

I watched a Google I/O video on GWT performance that recommended using Cell Widgets as much as possible because they are faster and lighter-weight than normal Widgets.

I am trying to determine if I should use either:

- `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button` (Button Widget); or
- `com.google.gwt.cell.client.ButtonCell` (Cell Widget)

I have read somewhat conflicting literature on widgets and cells; some authors say to only use cells when you don't have any events that need to be responded to.

So I ask: is it true that cell widgets don't have handlers and can't respond to events? If so, what's the use of a `ButtonCell` that will surely be clicked! And if it's not true, then it kind of seems like cell widgets are a total *replacement* for the "old" widget framework - is that true, or are there still use cases for `Button` and its other "old" widget kindred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, ButtonCell is not a "cell widget", it's a "cell", which is used by cell widget like CellList or CellTable to render it's content.

Cell widgets used for displaying large amount of similar-structured data (lists/tables), and for rendering a particular "cell" in such tables - you should use these lightweight stateless widgets (ButtonCell, TextCell). The benefits come from less amount of resulting dom-elements and JS. Also, CellWidgets still can receive browser events, but you should specify it explicitly. More on this topic - see [official Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells).

If you do not use cell widgets - you don't need to use cells, for example if you want to make a user-input form and put some labels and buttons - use Label and Button widgets, if you need to show a list of >100 rows - you might want to use TextCell and ButtonCell within CellList widget.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Mormysh (+1) - I'm still a little confused though! I didn't make the connection between the name "ButtonCell", "Cell", etc. to "table **cells**". Are cells really only meant for rendering widgets inside the rows of tables or lists with lots of data? If so then it makes sense as to why you would want them to be lightweight (a table with 10,000 rows might need 10,000 buttons!). Can you just confirm if I'm understanding you correctly, and if not, please give me a concrete example of when one would use a cell widget? Thanks again!

Comment: On that same note, what's wrong with always organizing your panel as a table and then adding cell widgets to it? That seems like a way to "cheat" and only use cell widgets! Can cells live outside of a table, or do they need to be bound to some kind of parent table?

Comment: Using cells makes sense only if the same instance is used for rendering multiple objects. See [CellTable](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) example - there columns are rendered by same set of cells, e.g. there is only one instance of cell for column "Category" wich is used to render different data and for processing events from different dom-elements.